# Jquery function running properly once, then stops waiting for a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while now, but I'm still relatively new to jquery.

I have a web site where I need an element to expand to 60% height when a button is pressed, switch the class and element, then wait for the 'hide mockups' button to be pressed. If it is pressed I need the height of that element to go back to 0% (so it basically disappears).

I need this to be universal so I can use it on many different elements on the same page (hence why I'm using $(this)). It worked before but I had the issue that if I pressed one button all of the elements with that class would ''expand''.

So I've come across another issue. I've fixed the issue of all the elements expanding but now the element will expand and close properly only ONCE.

If I press the 'hide mockup' button and try to 'show mockup' again the element will expand and collapse without waiting for the '.click(hidemock)' event. It seems to still be changing the classes but it does it really fast. Everything seems to be working fine but it just expands to 60% and back to 0% over 600ms without waiting for any input.

Does anyone have any input on this? I've been on this for hours now and can't figure it out.

Here's my code:

```js
$(function(){
 b = $(".show-mockup-button");
 $(b).click(f);
});
function f() {
 var b = $(this);
 var id = $(this).attr("name");//get id of range
 console.log(id);
 var idx = "#" + id; //turn into a html id
  $(idx).animate({ //start animation
   height: "60%"
      },350, function() {
       //finished
      }); //end animation
 $(function() {
  $(b).text("HIDE MOCKUPS");
  $(b).attr("class", "hide-mockup-button");
 });
 
  $(function() {
   var h = $(".hide-mockup-button");
   $(h).click(hidemock);
  });
  function hidemock() {
    var hn = $(this).attr("name");
    var hnx = "#" + hn;
    console.log(hnx);
    $(hnx).animate({ //start animation
    height: "0%"
        },350, function() {
         //finished
        }); //end animation
    $(function() {
     $(b).text("SHOW MOCKUPS");
     $(b).attr("class", "show-mockup-button");
    });
  };
};
```

@EDIT

HTML:

```html
<div class="mockupsec">
      <div class="show-mockup-button" name="222">SHOW MOCKUPS</div>
      <div class="mockup-show" id="222">
       <div class="container" id="222-Expansion">
        <div class="title">
         <p>Expansion</p>
        </div>
         <div class="imagerow">
         <div class="imagecol">
                                          <img class="" src="some src">
          <div class="item-text-wrapper">
           <p class="itemtitle"></p>
           <p class="itemcomment"></p>
          </div>
          
         </div>
         <div class="imagecol">
          <img class="" src="some src">
          <div class="item-text-wrapper">
           <p class="itemtitle"></p>
           <p class="itemcomment"></p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Its just a piece of the whole page so hopefully it pasted in correctly. Should give you an idea of what's where.

TIA.

Comment: Try using "id" instead of "class" .

Comment: Issue persists but thanks.